# How to disable the Facebook App Name from appearing when sharing on Facebook

Tags: ios, facebook, share

As the title suggests how to disable the name from appearing when sharing on Facebook. Is it default?

For example, I want to remove the part "via HelloFBSample":

[image]

This is because when you click that text, it appears like this:

[image]

How to avoid this? Need some guidance on this...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to disable it.

BTW, the link is only failing because it's a sample app, and there's no website or Facebook page set up for the app. If you built an app and configured it with either a web address or Facebook page, it would redirect to that instead.

Comment: How to configure it to the correct website? How to do the configuring part?

Comment: Figured it out. Change the siteurl in website link with facebook app.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the built-in sharing functionality of iOS, [SLComposeViewController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Reference/SLComposeViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012205), this should show that the post was made with Facebook for iOS and avoid your problem.